# Postgres in Docker port matching

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I need to run several equals Postgres containers on different ports via docker-compose. My problem is that I do not understand how to connect from my terminal to container's psql.

First of all, I should say that my local Postgres is off, so 5432 is free. Also I have `listen_addresses = '*'` in my containers.

Here is list of my attempts (to make it easier, I've posted examples for one Postgres container):

1. Run without port specifying

docker-compose.yml:

```
    version: "3"
    services:
        postgres:
            build: 
                context: ../../
                dockerfile: db-load-test/sharding-benchmark/Dockerfile
            environment: 
                - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
```

check port:

```
$ docker-compose ps

            Name                           Command              State    Ports  
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
sharding-benchmark_postgres_1   docker-entrypoint.sh postgres   Up      5432/tcp
```

try to connect:

```
$ psql -p 5432 -U postgres
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
        Is the server running locally and accepting
        connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

```
$ psql -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres
psql: could not connect to server: Connection refused
        Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

```
$ psql -h 0.0.0.0 -p 5432 -U postgres
psql: could not connect to server: Connection refused
        Is the server running on host "0.0.0.0" and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

2. Specify port and expose it in .yaml (I've changed 5432 to 5433 to make it more expressive)

```
$ docker-compose ps
            Name                           Command              State                          Ports                        
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
sharding-benchmark_postgres_1   docker-entrypoint.sh postgres   Up      5432/tcp, 0.0.0.0:49162->5433/tcp,:::49162->5433/tcp
```

Similar attempts to connect was unsuccessful. Also it's unclear to my why Postgres still listen 5432:

```
postgres_1  | 2021-08-02 12:49:01.394 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
postgres_1  | 2021-08-02 12:49:01.394 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
postgres_1  | 2021-08-02 12:49:01.397 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
```

3. Use docker directly

`docker run --rm -it -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres -p 5432:5432/tcp postgres:11`
It works with `psql -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres`, but if I use docker run with `5432:5433` it breaks, which is unclear to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `docker-compose.yml` file, you need to specify `ports:` for each of the database containers.  In each of these the second number *must* be the normal port for the database (5432); the first number can be any number of your choosing that's not used by another container or host process.

```yaml
version: '3'
  services:
    pg1:
      image: postgres
      # Use default PostgreSQL port 5432 on the host
      ports: ['5432:5432']
    pg2:
      image: postgres
      # First port must be different from pg1's above
      # Second port must be exactly 5432
      ports: ['5433:5432']
```

When you connect from the host, use a host name of `localhost` and the first published `ports:` number.  (If you're using the older Docker Toolbox setup, use the `docker-machine ip` address of the Docker VM; if you're connecting from a different host, use the Docker host's DNS name or IP address.)

```sh
# connect to pg1
psql -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres
# connect to pg2
psql -h localhost -p 5433 -U postgres
```

You do not need to `expose:` ports in the `docker-compose.yml` file; this doesn't really actually do anything.  You shouldn't need to reconfigure the stock `postgres` image beyond its basic environment-variable settings.  It doesn't make sense to connect to 0.0.0.0, a special address that means "everywhere" when you're setting up a network listener.

If you're connecting from a different container, none of this matters.  Use the Compose service name of the other container (like `pg2`) and the standard port number (5432).  `ports:` are completely ignored, and `localhost` means "this container".  The two containers must be on the same Docker network; Compose will create a network named `default` and just using that without explicit `networks:` settings is fine.